# Relationship mapping table with additional properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-relationship

I have three classes:

```
public partial class Student : Contact
{   
    //Inherited from Contact:
    //public int ContactId { get; set; }
    //public string FirstName { get; set; }
    //public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentExam StudentExam { get; set; }
}

public partial class Exam
{
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentExam StudentExam { get; set; }
}

public partial class StudentExam
{
    public byte Score { get; set; }
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
}
```

When trying to initialize the DbContext, it throws a `ModelValidationException`:
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
*\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'StudentExam' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'StudentExams' is based on type 'StudentExam' that has no keys defined.*

I tried changing the `StudentExam` class' properties to the following:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Student"), Column(Order = 0)]
public int ContactId { get; set; }
[Key, ForeignKey("Exam"), Column(Order = 1)]
public int ExamId { get; set; }
```

Now I get this exception:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'StudentExam_Student_Source' in relationship 'StudentExam_Student'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'StudentExam_Exam_Source' in relationship 'StudentExam_Exam'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Is there any way to achieve this in with data annotations (I don't like using the fluent API when I can use data annotations; The fluent API leads to messy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not about data annotations or fluent api but about incorrectly defined classes - relations defined in your classes cannot be mapped at all because they are not valid at relational level. You must modify your classes:

```
public partial class Student : Contact
{   
    public virtual ICollection<StudentExam> StudentExams { get; set; }
}

public partial class Exam
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<StudentExam> StudentExams { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have this relations defined you can use your data annotations for defining keys in `StudentExam` class and it will work.

Btw. fluent api doesn't lead to messy code. Messy code is created by programmer, not by API. Data annotations in turn violates POCO principle.

Comment: I keep my POCOs clean, I add metadata to it later. The profit of adding the metadata is also the independent validation (is this also achievable with fluent?). Anyway, by messy code I meant that all the fluent code goes into one `OnModelCreated` method rather than on each individual entity (by implementation of such method or other). I'm dealing with generated entities, so their anyway not real open-edge POCOs (it uses the constructor to initialize nav. properties, and thus a ctor cannot be written in the partial class. Sln was I added an `OnCreated` partial method and call in the gen. entity.