# EF Multiplicity constraint violated. The role ... of the relationship ... has multiplicity 1 or 0..1

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am getting the error

```
Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'BegrotingsCategorie_children_Source' of the relationship 'NET.DAL.EF.BegrotingsCategorie_children' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
```

when trying to read a 'BegrotingsCategorie' from my database.
This piece of code triggers the exception

```
 public BegrotingsCategorie ReadBegrotingsCategorie(int begrotingsCategorieId)
        {
            return _ctx.Begrotingscategorieen.Find(begrotingsCategorieId);
        }
```

My BegrotingsCategorie model looks like this

```
 [Table("tblBegrotingsCategorieen")]
    public class BegrotingsCategorie
    {
        [Key]
        public int BegrotingsCategorieId { get; set; }
        public string Informatie { get; set; }
        public double Uitgaven { get; set; }
        public Begroting Begroting { get; set; }
        public BegrotingsCategorie Parent { get; set; }
        public double Percentage { get; set; } 
        public double BerekendLoon { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BegrotingsCategorie> children { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Actie> Acties { get; set; }

    }
```

I have no idea how to solve this..

**Edit**
Some rows in the database

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF9fL.png)

The first row is the parent so its Parent_BegrotingsCategorieId is NULL,
it has 1 child with Parent_BegrotingsCategorieId 1 who on its own also has multiple children so they have Parent_BegrotingsCategorieId 2

I add my data like this

```
public BegrotingsCategorie AddBegrotingsCategorie(string informatie, Begroting begroting, BegrotingsCategorie parentCategorie)
        {
            BegrotingsCategorie begrotingsCategorie = new BegrotingsCategorie()
            {
                Informatie = informatie,
                Begroting = begroting,
                Parent = parentCategorie
            };
            return _repo.CreateBegrotingsCategorie(begrotingsCategorie);
        }
```

Comment: Could you show BegrotingsCategorie class and the Fluent API mapping for those classes? Keep in mind it has to have a FK to the Category class to establish the 1-to-many relationship.

Comment: The begrotingsCategorie class is shown above, the list 'children' has a Parent from the same class.

If I add [ForeignKey("Parent")] above children, I get this error
`The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'children' on type 'NET.BL.Domain.Begroting.BegrotingsCategorie' is not valid. The foreign key name 'Parent' was not found on the dependent type 'NET.BL.Domain.Begroting.BegrotingsCategorie'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.`

Comment: you need an Id of type int where you can add the attribute ForeignKey. This allows your DBMS to self join your table using the ForeignKey=primary key constraint.

Comment: Hmm, but the weird thing is that it worked until a few hours ago.. And there are 3500 rows of data in my database so it's not easy to add a new ForeignKey attribute..

Comment: what exactly did you change then? this relationship could have never worked without a foreign key defined.

Comment: I don't think I have changed anything, that's the weird thing, I think it should have never worked but I did..

Comment: what do some example rows look like, and how was the relationship established?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I edited my post. I realise that what I tried was impossible and that I will have to add a foreign key..

Comment: EF made its own FK called Parent_BegrotingsCategorieId. You can add this property manually and declare it as FK, then the schema does not need to be altered.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro This fixed it! + another mistake someone in my group made, he tried to get 1 BegrotingsCategorie and got returned multiple.. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: the InverseProperty at this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732440/multiplicity-constraint-violated-the-role-person-projects-source-of-the-relat

Answer (score -1):

I think your `ICollection<BegrotingsCategorie> children` property is giving you noise in your `BegrotingsCategorie` class. There is a one or zero-to-one  recursive relationship of `BegrotingsCategorie`s defined somewhere in your code. However, you are trying to use a one-to-many relationship of `BegrotingsCategorie`s in your class by declaring your property `children`as an `ICollection`. You may want to get rid of your `children` property in your `BegrotingsCategorie`class if you really do not need it. This may be a possible workaround.

Comment: this is not the core of the question. because there is no FK defined, EF uses PK=FK and therefore finds an one-to-one relationship, but there is a one-to-many defined using ICollection, that's why this error is raised.

Comment: @downvoter, can you please tell us why you did it so we all can learn something new?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I do not know what the intent of the OP was in the sense of really needing the `children` property as he already had a one or zero-to-one constraint defined before. I invite you to post your comments as an answer and let the OP decide which answer suits better his needs.